# javascript dynamically navigate in multi dimensioned array content

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was building something with google maps and I wrote this piece of code to fill the infowindows:

```
  mouseover: function(marker, event, context){

    var numManc = context.data.num_manc;
    var elencoManc = '';

    for(i=1;i<=numManc;i++)
    {
        var mymanc = i;
        elencoManc = elencoManc + context.data.mancinita.mymanc.mancinita;
    }

   etc....
```

I alsway get this error **TypeError: context.data.mancinita.mymanc is undefined**.

Actually what I need is that the var "elencoManc" concatenate itself N times, where N equals the var "numManc".

So in the "for" loop I should get something like

```
elencoManc = elencoManc + context.data.mancinita.1.mancinita;
elencoManc = elencoManc + context.data.mancinita.2.mancinita;
elencoManc = elencoManc + context.data.mancinita.3.mancinita;


elencoManc = elencoManc + context.data.mancinita.N.mancinita;
```

It seems that I cannot make that concat dynamic.

This is one record stored in the array:

```
{
                        lat: 35.110901,
                        lng: 12.876027,
                        options: {
                            icon: "icon_2.png",
                            },
                        data: {
                            nome: "Name of the sotre",
                            indirizzo: "Address of the sotre",
                            city: "Rome",
                            linkStore: "http://www.storelink.com",
                            immagine_copertina: "asset/imageStore.png",
                            city: "Rome",
                            num_tipi: 1,
                            num_manc: 2,
                            tipi_1: {
                               icona_tipo: "asset/ico/ico2.png",
                               tipo: "negozio_bio"
                            },
                            mancinita: {
                               1: {
                                    icona: "iconManc2.png",
                                    idmanc: 2,
                                    mancinita: "organic"
                                  },
                               2: {
                                    icona: "iconManc5.png",
                                    idmanc: 5,
                                    mancinita: "lowFat"
                            },

                           },
                          distanza: "0.000"
                          }
                         }
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: elencoManc = elencoManc + context.data.mancinita[i].mancinita;

Comment: @Donal thanks. Why am I getting this error now?
`SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`

Comment: Not sure. But you have a duplicate key in your JSON.                             city: "Rome" appears twice!

Comment: your first suggestion about the array index was correct. Thanks again. By the way there was an exceding comma in json that caused the system to crash. It wasn't the "city=rome" duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your JSON. For example city: "Rome" appears twice. 
If you fix them, then something like this should work (assuming context is the same as your JSON):

```
context.data.mancinita[1].mancinita
```

I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vz8cjuen/1/) with an example to show you:

```
var context = {
                        lat: 35.110901,
                        lng: 12.876027,
                        options: {
                            icon: "icon_2.png"
                            },
                        data: {
                            nome: "Name of the sotre",
                            indirizzo: "Address of the sotre",
                            city: "Rome",
                            linkStore: "http://www.storelink.com",
                            immagine_copertina: "asset/imageStore.png",
                                                        num_tipi: 1,
                            num_manc: 2,
                            tipi_1: {
                               icona_tipo: "asset/ico/ico2.png",
                               tipo: "negozio_bio"
                            },
                            mancinita: {
                               1: {
                                    icona: "iconManc2.png",
                                    idmanc: 2,
                                    mancinita: "organic"
                                  },
                               2: {
                                    icona: "iconManc5.png",
                                    idmanc: 5,
                                    mancinita: "lowFat"
                            }
                           },
                          distanza: "0.000"
                          }
                         };


console.log(context.data.mancinita[1].mancinita);
```

Comment: Damn! that was it! Thank you very much!